# Perforce Error: %t argument "No object selected in active pane" cannot run C:\Users\User\Perforce\testCutsomToot.bat

Tags: perforce, p4v, perforce-stream

I am trying to test 1 custom tool in perforce 
below steps i am doing :

1.) Click on Tools | Manage Custom Tools...
2.) Click on New | Tool...
i added new tool , but its giving error when i am passing %t as argument to the tool 
%t is the default argument of perforce

I am getting below error , while running this custom tool with argument %t which represents "selected stream in p4"

**Error output**: "No object selected in active pane" cannot run C:\Users\User\Perforce\testCutsomToot.bat"

my script contains below 3 lines:

echo Success

set arg1=%1

echo %arg1%

Comment: Are you selecting a stream with the mouse before you run the tool?  "Selected stream" means a stream that's selected in the UI, not the stream associated with your workspace.

Comment: thanks @sam stafford i also noticed  same that if i select stream in graph it works, but its surprising and i was expecting that stream associated with workspace should be printed in output

Comment: You don't need this to be passed in as a parameter -- just have your tool use `p4 -Ztag -F %Stream% client -o`

Answer (score 2):

On further investigation I found that , %t will print correct output if we choose the stream fist in streams graph UI and then run the custom tool 
so we need to select stream as shown below highlighted

[image]